# Plotting dynamic variable generated by checking Region intersections

Tags: plotting, manipulate, graphics3d, dynamic, regions

I have been trying to plot a variable which is nested inside a manipulate. Here is a simplified version of the program.

```
pts = Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 10}];
Manipulate[
R1 = Cylinder[{{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 2}}, x];
R2 = Cylinder[{{7, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 2}}, x];
R3 = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
productY = Count[RegionMember[R3, pts], True];
Column[{
Text[productY],
Graphics3D[{
 Point[pts],
 Opacity[0.1],
 R1,
 R2
}],
Plot[productY, {t, 0, 10}]
}], {{x, 1, "variable x"}, 1, 5, 1}]
```

This creates a program which looks like this:

[image]

The program shows "5" as 5 dots are within the intersection of the two cylinders with radius "x". What I would like to plot is a graph of the number of dots within the intersection against variable x. Any ideas...?

Thank you.

Comment: Nothing is clear from these explanations. Give an example of your code from start to finish.

Comment: Alright. Lemme try to get a simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also acquire a symbolic solution to this question with `Total` of `Boole` (truth value to 0/1) values of membership on parametric regions:

```
FullSimplify@
 Total[Function[{u, v, w}, 
    Evaluate@
     Boole@RegionMember[
       RegionIntersection[
        Cylinder[{{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 2}}, x], 
        Cylinder[{{7, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 2}}, x]], {u, v, w}]] @@@ 
   Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 10}]]
```

> Boole[x >= 2] + 
>    2 (Boole[x >= 3] + Boole[x >= 4] + Boole[x >= 5] + Boole[x >= 6] + Boole[x >= 7])

And plot it:

```
Plot[FullSimplify@
  Total[Function[{u, v, w}, 
     Evaluate@
      Boole@RegionMember[
        RegionIntersection[
         Cylinder[{{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 2}}, x], 
         Cylinder[{{7, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 2}}, x]], {u, v, w}]] @@@ 
    Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 10}]], {x, 1, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you can rip out the inner part of your code above and use `ListLinePlot` by creating a table containing `{x, productY}` elements:

```
pts = Table[{i, 0, 1}, {i, 0, 10}];
ListLinePlot[
 Table[{x,
   R1 = Cylinder[{{3, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 2}}, x];
   R2 = Cylinder[{{7, 0, 0}, {7, 0, 2}}, x];
   R3 = RegionIntersection[R1, R2];
   Count[RegionMember[R3, pts], True]},
  {x, 5}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]